# Shopping Cart - The flow for sold out or less available items at checkout time?

Tags: workflow, shopping-cart, solution, concept

I designed a shopping cart solution for a client. For one of their items (candy, for example), they have a certain quantity they can sell for each type. I deduct from the quantity available ***after*** items have been purchased.

The candy shopping flow is as follow:

1. Select (add to cart) candy on candy catalog page
2. Go to Cart page to review items to be purchased
3. Go to checkout page (billing information + list of items to be purchased with price total details)

Pertinent Situation:
**Customer A** select 9 of the remaining 10 Snickers. **Customer B** selects 5 of the remaining 10 Snickers. At checkout, **Customer B** submits his payment information (leaving 5 snickers left) before **Customer A**, who bought *9* Snickers.

Now, **Customer A** will be left with a message on the checkout page about what happened (i.e. - *Oops.. yur candiez r all gone!*), including a list of which candy is sold out, or less available. Here, I am unsure as to where the flow should continue (hoping this was even a good path to begin with).

Should the customer be given a link back to their shopping cart where the items they selected are unchanged, and be left for them to remove and continue purchasing? Or, should these items reflect the new quantities available for each item, such that since **Customer A** bought 9 Snickers, the cart will show *Customer A added 5 Snickers* (of the remaining 5)? Or, should these items be removed from the cart altogether?

**Another solution** (as suggested by Andreas Niedermair and E. Rodriguez): Deduct inventory as customers add items to their shopping cart.

If this were my implementation, at what point/how would I add items back into the inventory  if the customer leaves the site? My cart is not DB driven.

Any feedback would be great, and I will be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would introduce an intermediate state where the candiez are considered "sold" at the moment a quantity is selected. Depending on other cart features ("save ur candiez for laterz", for example) you might want to reallocate them back to the available inventory pool after a certain amount of time... but I believe that the moment the customer wants them, as in a store, if they put them in their cart (even without buying them) then the next customer only sees what is available.

Comment: Originally, I was coding out that solution, but I wasn't sure how to trigger a timed reallocation back to the inventory pool. (My cart isn't DB-driven, by the way)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I implemented, so I marked as answer.

Comment: Youre welcome, and thanks for the vote. If I didn't think the mod hammer would hit me on the head like Super Mario, I would have given you +1 for your humorous approach in your question. Making a question compelling helps a LOT. I think Joel Spolsky would be glad.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the other way: items, as they get added to the cart, get reserved for a certain amount of time (eg the session timeout).
If an item is sold out, or less amount is available at adding-time, the user gets an earlier hint. Remember: there's nothing more frustrating than getting a bad "oops" at checkout!

Comment: Let's say the user adds items to their cart, then leaves the site altogether. How and/or at what point would I reallocate the items into the inventory?

Comment: well, whether you take one approach or the other, i think thats a question you have to answer as far as when to add them back. if you want to make it a policy to have them expire on session end, or after 24 hours, or a week - the key is to have an intermediate method of managing inventory levels between when that user has "all the goods" and when other customers want to buy more of what is sold out. i agree that doing it at checkout is too late though. maybe some kind of alert at the top of the screen when a purchase is requested?

Comment: well, if you are running on asp.net there would be a session-end-event. otherwise I would add a timestamp of adding to your data-layer (what ever that may be) and query against it on "what's in stock right now"-check/display/...

Comment: I'm doing this in PHP (I should have tagged as such) and store the customer's items in their session.  I understand to add a timestamp here and then trigger the re-allocation after so much elapsed time. This is the part I'm most confused about, and I apologize, but how would I access a customer's session's timestamp when they are not perusing the site any longer?

Comment: Figured it out using PHP. Thanks for the insight guys. Both answers appear the same to me. When the user adds an item to their cart, it is reserved in their cart for as long as they're shopping (active time), once they've been inactive for 20 minutes, then all items are re-allocated into the inventory. I'm using a cron job to check session data (particularly, the timestamp) every minute.